# How do I get request parameters in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For the life of me I can't find out how to create a request object and pull in Get and Post parameters in ASP.NET MVC.

I can't define them in the actions constructor, I just want to pull the information from the request directly.

Comment: EF is a tool for querying databases.  Why would you be using it to access the query strings values of a web request?  They're orthogonal concepts.

Comment: Sorry I mean Microsofts MVC, it's been a long day

Comment: The fact you want to access the request parameters directly should ring a few bells about your design. One of the consequences of using the MVC paradigm is that you shouldn't worry about implementation details, which request parameters are.

Comment: It's often the case that, if you can't find how to do something (through searching), that you're not actually meant to be doing it. Look into model binding, unless there's some reason why you "can't define them in the actions constructor".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do:

```
string strParam = HttpContext.Current.Request["someParameter"];
```

Comment: thanks, its been a shift moving from linux to Microsoft, and I'm pretty sure I'm jumbling up some of the 1000 different new names haha.

Comment: To other's points though, you should be mapping request parameters in your routes to your controller methods.  By doing so MVC sends postback/query string parameters to your controller methods automatically.

Comment: I agree, but I'm currently just learning the language, adn going through all the different ways it allows. I've been easily able to set up and entire json api for the site, but was just curious on how the requests pass and type.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you have a queriable end point that you can expect 40 to 50 parameters that may or may not be defined by the caller, how do you usually handle that in your controller action?

Comment: you create a method with all 50 parameters, and parameters not specified in the query string will be null.

Comment: Optionally, you could create a custom model binder that can detect that the query string is for some specific web service.  Then you can create a class with properties to represent the web service calls options.  In the same custom model binder, when it detects the call (e.g. isSomeWebService=1) it Instantiates your custom object (code you write) and fills it with all the data from the query string and then passes it off to a method on your controller, in such a way your controller can have 1 parameter instead of 50 (1 being the object with all the options in it pulled from the query string).

Comment: nice answer it solved me an issue with a drag & drop control

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can also do this in your route configuration.

You should have a global class file in your project "global.asax/global.cs" and in there should be code to configure the Controller Routes, for example....

```
    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("ImageGen_GetImage", "ImageGen/{action}", new { controller = "ImageGen", action = "GetImage", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

Then your controller method might look like this,

```
        [HttpGet()]
    public void GetImage(string localImageUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, string cache)
    {
    }
```

In this example scenario none of the parameters on GetImage are in the route url "ImageGen/{action}".

As such when you request http://www.somesite.com/imagegen/getimage MVC knows imagegen is mapped to the ImageGen controller.  As such it also knows that {action} here is being stated as "GetImage" (because it comes after imagegen in the url and matches the url in the mapping in that order).  Now because no other parameters are set in the url of the mapping MVC auatomatically assumes the parameters on the GetImage method are coming from the query string.

So if you were to go to http://www.somesite.com/imagegen/GetImage?localImageUrl=/images/myImage.png&maxWidth=1024&maxHeight=768&cache=1

Then GetImage will be called with localImageUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, and cache values pulled from the query string, Automagically.